# Ubuntu 16.04: Cannot add path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: c++, ubuntu-16.04

I want to use an additional library when compiling an application but I am not able to add the path to the library directory to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` hence it's not found by the build system:

I added the path to the library directory `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`, in a new file petsc.conf which contains `/home/klaus/OpenFOAM/klaus-5.0/petsc-3.7.6/arch-linux2-c-debug/lib`

and when I run `ldconfig -p` the library IS found but it doesn't appear in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

I also added the path to `.bashrc`

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/klaus/OpenFOAM/klaus-5.0/petsc-3.7.6/arch-linux2-c-debug/lib`

sourced it, later rebooted but when I check `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with

`env | grep '^LD_LIBRARY_PATH'`

the library is still not included and I get a compile error that it's not found (linked)

What needs to be done on top of these steps to add a library to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is for dynamic loaded library. In that path that have compiled your `.so` try `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD`

Answer (score 2):

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` doesn't affect linking. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is used at load time to override default library search paths. You should use full path to your library (like `g++ -l/path/to/mylib/lib_mylib.so ...`) or provide search path (like `g++ -L/path/to/mylib/`)

At run time, use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or link with `-rpath` option (to add non default library search path at link time).

Answer (score 0):

Assume I am using `libfunc.so` in a file names `temp.c`

---

`man 3 dlopen`:

```
       dlclose, dlopen, dlmopen - open and close a shared object

SYNOPSIS
       #include <dlfcn.h>

       void *dlopen(const char *filename, int flags);

       int dlclose(void *handle);

       #define _GNU_SOURCE
       #include <dlfcn.h>

       void *dlmopen (Lmid_t lmid, const char *filename, int flags);

       Link with -ldl.
```

#### first way to use dynamic library (= directly tell the linker):

```
ALP ❱ gcc temp.c -ldl
ALP ❱ ./a.out
libfunc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ALP ❱ pwd
/home/shu/codeblock/ALP
ALP ❱ gcc temp.c -ldl -Wl,-rpath,/home/shu/codeblock/ALP
ALP ❱ ./a.out
func1: 1
func2: upgrading to version 2
```

#### second way to use dynamic library (= using environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`):

```
ALP ❱ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD
ALP ❱ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/home/shu/codeblock/ALP
ALP ❱ ./a.out
func1: 1
func2: upgrading to version 2
ALP ❱ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=
ALP ❱ ./a.out
libfunc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

#### third way to use dynamic library (= copy it to a standard  path):

```
ALP $ sudo cp libfunc.so /usr/lib
ALP ❱ gcc temp.c -ldl
ALP ❱ ./a.out
func1: 1
func2: upgrading to version 2
```

---

**NOTE**

how to find that a path is in your `a.out` file
first compile it and use `strings` and `grep`:

```
ALP ❱ gcc temp.c -ldl -Wl,-rpath,/home/shu/codeblock/ALP
ALP ❱ strings a.out  | grep \/
/lib/ld-linux.so.2
/home/shu/codeblock/ALP
```

---

have been tested on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Nothing of this is being asked, and `sudo cp libfunc.so /usr/lib`? Huh? Don't touch your system directories.

Comment: I'm not talking about rights, I'm talking about sensible behaviour. You have a right to wreck your system sure. And of course you don't have much rights on a system which isn't yours.

Comment: Since you have a higher score than me let yourself to tell me that. Eventually a shared object goes to a standard path and of course standard path is for this like other files that are there.

Comment: If you build a Linux distro, you decide what goes in /usr/lib. Otherwise, nope, your libraries most definitely don't go to /usr/lib.

Comment: **First** `cp` a `lib` for test has no problem **never** since it can be `rm -f` later. **Second** my answer is prefect then the other ones and I just let the user/OP choose one of them; it is even better that one as marked  duplicated. Anyway thank you for letting me know you better.

Comment: I have no desire to continue this fruitless exchange. I have downvoted and explained what's wrong, I've done my part.

Comment: Likewise me. I told you before; when you down-voted me for an undefined behavior in a `C++` code. Instead of being so strict to others, you could be friendly and modify my answer and make it better if you see any problems. The only thing that I did not mention is **warning/telling** to `rm` after doiing `cp`. I know/remember your answer already. You do not want to modify/edit others question. have a nice day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156032/discussion-between-n-m-and-k-five).